# How do I return an auto generated numeric ID from the key in google app engine?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, servlets

Heres my code

```
Entity post = new Entity("Post");
int ID = post.getKey().getId();
post.setProperty("ID", ID);
```

But the ID shows as 0 in my datastore.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't have an id `getId()` until the entity has been put to the datastore.

Why would you store the id from the Key as an property of an entity. It is completely redundant. Also the id of the key can't be changed re-inforcing redundancy.

Comment: I want to be able to retrieve the id number from an entity object by querying for a certain property. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If you have id, and you know the Kind that you are looking for then you could just fetch it object by the Key.  No point querying.

Comment: The thing is I don't have the id since its auto generated. I want to be able to find the id by one of the properties.

Comment: Once you put the entity, then the key has the id. So you can get it after you put with `int ID = post.getKey().getId();`

Comment: Storing the ID as a property after the put, still doesn't achieve anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use method **allocateIds** to generate unique ID.

Here is an example.

```
DatastoreService datastoreService = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

KeyRange keyRange = datastoreService.allocateIds("CartItem", 1L);

// you have ID here before save
Entity item = new Entity(keyRange.getStart());
datastoreService.put(item);
```